# Word overwrites List Level 2 ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent after calling Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm using a linked style for my custom ListTemplate. I'm assigning a list indent like so:

```
lvl2Style.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = 24;
```

But when I step through my code, as soon as I apply the list to my selected range, it resets the FirstLineIndent to 18 points only on List Level 2.

```
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(list, continuePrevious, missing);
```

Does anyone know how to prevent Word from overriding my values?  I'm not interested in bullying Word after applying the list template if I can avoid it.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773341/word-style-is-changed-after-applying-applylisttemplate?answertab=votes#tab-top) but doesn't answer my question on how to prevent Word from changing my set values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is by-design and cannot be "turned off".

Applying a list template always overrides directly applied indent formatting or indent formatting defined in a paragraph style - the list template takes priority.

The indent fomatting must be included in the list template's definition, or should be applied *after* applying the list template.

Comment: Thank you Cindy.  So you're saying if I re-apply my style AFTER the applying code, I should be good to go?

Comment: @NickMetnik Based on the information provided in the question: provisionally, yes. However, this is not "robust". But without knowing why this particular paragraph requires a different first-line indent than other level 2 paragraphs it's not possible to suggest any possible alternatives. But that would be a discussion for an end-user venue...

Comment: Thanks again.  To answer the why, each level has a client specific indentation and that varies by font and font size.  It's a deal breaker if I can't get passed Word resetting values, no client flexibility here.  I'll mark as answer because it certainly gives me direction in the order to my code execution.

Comment: @NickMetnik ?Client-specific indentation? Is it the same throughout a particular document? Or does it change within the document?

Comment: Client specific indentation for the government, 8 level lists.  No wiggle room on the indentation.  It is the same throughout the document though, but need to update the styles and list when a user chooses one other font and size.

Comment: So, if you knew how to change the indent setting in the ListTemplate that would solve your problem? Or am I still missing something @NickMetnik?

Comment: I've applied my indentation after the ApplyListTemplate call and Word ignores the value.  I'm really not sure what I need to do here anymore.

Comment: Sorry Cindy, just saw your comment.  I guess so, I thought the following was setting it, works on all the other levels except level 2.

    style.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = indentation;

Comment: @NickMetnik So, are you able (know how) to change the ListTemplate definition? If not, post a new question, please. In it, specify whether you're dealing with a custom `ListTemplate` or one that comes with Word (and which one). I'm guessing that means what's assigned to `list` in the code snippet in the question... Also include more code syntax and a screen shot of what you need.

Comment: Hello Cindy, yes.  I'm adding a custom ListTemplate to the document.  I'll edit my original question to include more code and a screen shot.

Comment: @NickMetnik No, don't edit the original question - that's not the way Stack Overflow is designed to work. Post a new question, PLEASE. The original question has been answered.